# I want some extra fields on magento 2.1.2 api

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, sku, magento-2.1.2

```
What I get :
    http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/263/products
    [{
        "sku": "20130",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "263"
      },
      {
        "sku": "20134",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "263"
      },
    ]

What I want :
    http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/263/products
    [{
        entity_id: "2"
        type_id: "simple"
        sku: "Levis Bagpack"
        description: "Bagpack"
        short_description: "Bagpack"
        meta_keyword: null
        name: "Levis Bagpack"
        meta_title: null
        meta_description: null
        regular_price_with_tax: 45
        regular_price_without_tax: 45
        final_price_with_tax: 45
        final_price_without_tax: 45
        is_saleable: true
        image_url: "http://example.com/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg"
     },
     {
        entity_id: "3"
        type_id: "simple"
        sku: "Levis Bagpack Silver"
        description: "Bagpack Silver"
        short_description: "Bagpack Silver"
        meta_keyword: null
        name: "Levis Bagpack Silver"
        meta_title: null
        meta_description: null
        regular_price_with_tax: 45
        regular_price_without_tax: 45
        final_price_with_tax: 45
        final_price_without_tax: 45
        is_saleable: true
        image_url: "http://example.com/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg"
     }
    ]
```

Comment: Create your own API which extend of the native implementation/interface or extend the current API in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own API in a custom module.

Base on this native implementation :

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkManagement::getAssignedProducts
```

Load product data

Create your custom `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface` to expose your custom product values

About image URL, you need to emulate the frontend area in order to generate the correct path.

Be careful about performance issue.